# WPF: Trigger animations on elements by name from EventTrigger on a dynamically created control

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, event-triggers

I have a Grid inside of an ItemsControl's DataTemplate, so there will be many copies of this grid.  I want a mouse click on the grid to trigger the storyboard of an element outside of the DataTemplate.  For example, I would like to animate Transform properties of a named element that exists elsewhere in the Window.

Let's say my DataTemplate looks something like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="myRectangle">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                 To="10" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                                 To="10" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                 To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                                 BeginTime="0:0:0.5" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

and somewhere in my window I have a Rectangle that looks like this:

```
    <Rectangle x:Name="myRectangle" Height="400" Width="400">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" ScaleY="0" />
                <TranslateTransform />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
```

When the MouseLeftButtonUp event fires, I get the following exception:

'myRectangle' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'.

Is there a way to tell the storyboard where to look for an element by this name?  I'm especially interested in a xaml-only solution if one exists.

Comment: I haven't found XAML solution to this, have to use code-behind. I'd also be interested to know the reason why the target should be in the scope of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to find xaml elements in a different namescope (i.e. external of the data template) by using the FindAncestor mode of a RelativeSource binding, as long as the xaml element you're trying to bind to is a parent element.  The binding code would look like:

```
{Binding Path="myRectangle", RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Rectangle}}}
```

Name bindings in storyboards may be a different animal entirely, but perhaps you can use this.